# Calculating parameter on raster using gdal and python

Tags: python, gdal

I'm trying to create a script which reads an array of rasters and calculate a parameter, but I get this error:

> operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2718,4310) (70,86).

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np
import sys ,os
from osgeo.gdalconst import *
output_dir='C:\\wamp\\www\\Donnees_CRTS\\irrisat_dessimination-smiej'
etp = os.path.join(output_dir,"L8_L8_ETpot_24_30m_2016_223.tif")
rain = os.path.join(output_dir,"GLDAS_NOAH025SUBP_3H.A2016223.sumday.rain.tif")
eff = os.path.join(output_dir,"eff_v11.tif")
driver=gdal.GetDriverByName('GTIff')
driver.Register()
paths = []
paths.append(etp)
paths.append(rain)
paths.append(eff)
raster_px = []
rasters_px = []
bands = []
def open_raster(raster):       
    for i in range(len(paths)) :
       raster = gdal.Open(paths[i])
       columns = raster.RasterXSize
       lines = raster.RasterYSize
       band = raster.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray(0,0,columns,lines)
       bands.append(band)
       gt=raster.GetGeoTransform()
       raster_px.append(gt)
    
       band=None  
   if raster is None :
    print ("Erreur : Impossible d'ouvrir le raster: ")
   try :
    smallest = min(raster_px)
    raster.SetGeoTransform(smallest)

    
   except:
    print ("Erreur : Impossible d'extraire la bande")

  return smallest,  columns, lines



def parameters(parameter) :
    diff = bands[0]-bands[1]
   if parameter == "IWR" :
     iwr=diff/bands[2]
return iwr



def createImage(new_image,columns,lines,smallest):

    new_image=driver.Create("iwr9.tif", columns,lines, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
    new_image.SetProjection("EPSG:4326")
    new_image.SetGeoTransform(smallest)
    new_image.GetRasterBand(1).WriteRaster( 0, 0, columns, lines, output_dir 
  )
  new_image=None
  return columns, lines

def main() :

smallest, columns, lines = open_raster(paths)
p = "IWR"

parameters(p)
createImage("iwr9.tif",columns, lines,smallest)
main()
```

Comment: python tells you at which line the error occurs. Could you please highlight for us where in your code the error happens? Generally the error means that you are trying to fill a matrix with shape rows: 2718 and columns: 4310 with a matrix of shape rows: 70 columns: 86.

Comment: thaks for your quick answer. the error is in the line 50

Comment: please indicate the content of that line. Counting to 50 left me in a blank line.

Comment: diff = bands[0]-bands[1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you do the following:

You have three different .tif-files, each containing one band. You read the content of these images into (numpy)-arrays and store them in a list of arrays, called `bands`. So `band[0]` is an array of etp, `band[1]` is an array of rain, `band[2]` is an array of eff. These three arrays have a x&y-dimension (i.e. the dimensions of the image/"picture").

`bands[1] - bands[0]` is an array division which means that you subtract the value of each array item from the item of the other array.

For instance

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])
y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
z = x - y # print(z): 9 18 27 36 45
```

The example above deals with 1D-array, but the same works for 2D-arrays. Now if python tells you that it cannot "broadcast" one array into the other, then it means that the item-wise calculation failed as the **shape of the arrays are different**. In the above example if `x` has length 5 but `y` has lenght 4, then numpy/python cannot know what to do with the missing items and throws an error.

You can check that by looking at the shape of your bands item (make sure you `import numpy as np`)

```
np.shape(bands[0])
np.shape(bands[1])
np.shape(bands[2])
```

Probably they will differ which causes your error. So at first you would have to make sure that all your images have the same size, before you perform pixel-wise algebra.

Comment: this is exactly what is happening, shapes of images are different. Now I'm working on doing a clip so that I can do my substraction.

Comment: Great! Make sure the remaining (clipped) images represent the same geo-location.  Otherwise you'd have to spatially resample (e.g. nearest neighbor) which can also be done in gdal (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/234022/resampling-a-raster-from-python-without-using-gdalwarp)

Comment: Please consider to mark this answer as "problem solved" or ask further if something is still unclear. Thanks!